# mvc4 sql query running and storing data (Database First Approach)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

I am making a very very Basic Inventory application using MVC4 ASP.NET in VS2012.
There is a field *Auto_id* in my *Item_master* table which is not a primary key but helps generating the primary key. The primary key is intended to be generated in the ItemController Class.

I want to execute a sql command as follows in the database and return the next Auto_id number. The Auto_id is a simple Integer field.

```
select max(Auto_id)+1 as aid from Item_master where Auto_id is not null
```

My Create() action method is as follows..

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Item_master item_master)
    {
        int xid = 0;
        String x = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            x = db.Item_master.SqlQuery("select max(Auto_id)+1 as aid from Item_master where Auto_id is not null").ToList().ToString();

            if (x != null)
                xid = int.Parse(x);
            else
                xid = 0;

            db.Item_master.Add(item_master);
            item_master.Auto_id = xid;
            item_master.Item_id = item_master.Item_type_id.ToString() + xid;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Item_type_id = new SelectList(db.Type_master, "Type_id", "Type", item_master.Item_type_id);
        return View(item_master);
    }
```

The Model class as generated and later edited by me is :

```
namespace DataEntry.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public partial class Item_master
{
    public Item_master()
    {
        this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Auto_id { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Item_id { get; set; }
    public string Item_name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Item_type_id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public virtual Type_master Type_master { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
}
```

I currently have not entered any data in the Item_master table.
When I try to enter a data using automatically scaffolded views I get the following exception:

[image: The The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Model.Item_master'. A member of the type, 'Auto_id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.]

It reads :

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Model.Item_master'. A member of the type, 'Auto_id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I know how to handle exceptions using `try{}catch(){}` but where is this error arising? What should I do?

Is there any alternate way to do what I intend?

I am learning asp.net mvc new. I have never used databases in such mvc application yet have experience in database working in oracle and I am mainly a php developer.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will try to map the result of your query to a collection of `Item_master` entity objects. But your query is not returning all the columns for this entity.

Since you are returning a scalar integer value from your query,you might consider using the generic `SqlQuery` method.There is no need to call the `ToList()` method and then `.ToString()` on top of that result. You can simply call the FirstOrDefault() method.

```
var maxId = 0;
var x = db.Database.SqlQuery<int?>("select max(Auto_id)+1 as Auto_id
                                               from Item_master where Auto_id is not null")
                                 .FirstOrDefault();
if (x != null)
{
    maxId= x.Value;
}
// Use maxId as needed.
```

While this might fix your problem, **I strongly suggest you look into [Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) feature provided by SQL server** which does the auto increment for you. That might be more safe than you manually generate it and use it. With your current approach. It is possible that 2 records can have the same `Auto_id` value.